# Adding RETURNING statement causes ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have created the following procedure, but it will not compile. I want to insert a row into a table, and then return the ID (sequence) for that newly inserted row into a variable. When I add the `returning` statement though I get the error: `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_PROC(
    l_MY_ID NUMBER
)
IS
  l_MY_OTHER_ID NUMBER;
BEGIN


INSERT INTO TABLE_A(
    NAME, 
    WEIGHT, 
    HEIGHT,
    HAIR
)
select 
"NAME", 
"WEIGHT", 
"HEIGHT",
"HAIR"
FROM
TABLE_A_VIEW
WHERE
"PERSON_ID" = l_MY_ID 
returning TABLE_A_ID INTO l_MY_OTHER_ID ;


END;
```

Comment: Don't use double quotes around upper-case identifiers; it just isn't necessary.

Comment: The short answer is "you cannot; `INSERT INTO ... RETURNING` is only valid with the `INSERT ... VALUES ...` and not with `INSERT ... SELECT ...`". This is documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423) in the `INSERT` syntax.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, thanks for the link!

Comment: There is an additional issue.  You declare a parameter  *l_MY_OTHER_ID number*, however you do not specify its usage as IN, OUT, INOUT so therefore it defaults to IN. As a result you cannot change it value. Declare is as *l_MY_OTHER_ID out number*.